# Different notification interval when service is critical

Tags: monitoring, nagios, alerts

I've got a service in Nagios that checks how much disk space is used on a server.

When over 80% is used, the service is in a `warning` state.  When it's over 97% it's considered `critical`.

When the service is in `warning` I want to send an alert once a day (`notification_interval 1440`).  When the service is critical I want to send an alert every two hours (`notification interval 120`).

How do I set this up?

Is it possible to set this up in one service or do I need to define two services, one that sends alerts for `warning` and another that sends alerts for `critical`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a [serviceescalation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#serviceescalation) with `notification_interval` set to 120 when the service is in `CRITICAL` state:

```
define serviceescalation{
    host_name               xx
    service_description     disk_free
    notification_interval   120
    .
    .
    escalation_period       24x7
    escalation_options      c
    }
```